# Deploy a ReactJs Application on Digitalocean with PHP API and APache server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, digital-ocean, npm-scripts

I have been trying to deploy my first react js application on Digital ocean for a few days now with no success. 
It is a create react app and it is connected to a PHP API running an Apache server

I have successfully build my application by using npm run build command. when I try to access the build folder from my browser, I just get a blank page. I do this by simply accessing the routing my browser to access domain_name.com/myapp/build ( just for test purposes).

When I run npm start, I can access the home of the application in development mode at domain.com:3000. The script section of my package.json looks as follow

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-scripts start",
  "build": "react-scripts build",
  "test": "react-scripts test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject",
  "add-locale": "lingui add-locale",
  "flow": "flow",
  "start:prod": 'node dist/app.js'
},
```

My server is running on https://domain_name.com but when i do  https://domain_name.com:3000, I can't access the dev version of my app but i can access the dev version with domain_name.com:3000.

any help around these issues will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: At first, I'm totally sure that you don't run anything on 3000 port on the server using Apache or at least you can't expose it. So all your files should be available on 80 port which means you should put it together with your hosted project files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you're running npm start you launch webpack-dev-server which runs on 3000 port and host your sources.

When you build your React app, you just prepare a single js file, which you should host with your Apache server together with your API files.

You need to include that js file in your index.html with structure and `<script src="path/to/js">` to that file.

Let me know if you still have any question.

#### Update:

To solve the problem with routing read [the official deployment manual](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing) and search `.htaccess`

P.S: maybe you find this https://gist.github.com/ywwwtseng/63c36ccb58a25a09f7096bbb602ac1de useful.

Comment: thanks @pavlo, I didnt know about editing the html file . where do I find the js file you are talking about. because, there is none in my project folder. when I access the build folder, i see two js files  precache-manifest.2267fe1d7db406484d550aef922b7138.js,  service-worker.js so which is correct ??

Comment: @NgesBrian your may find more info at https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment

Comment: @NgesBrian Looks like you need to put both of them together with `static` folder

Comment: it actually opens but no js is rendered. infact, just the background picture is showing

Comment: and when i change that particular route to another, i just find an empty not found page. infact, nothing is right here

Comment: Have you read this section https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#serving-apps-with-client-side-routing ?

Comment: > and when i change that particular route to another, i just find an empty not found page
/
/
Fix for this problem described in the manual. Please read it carefully.

Comment: Yes, I have read all, but i have a problem. it seems as if all explainations here are for static websites. My website is not a static website. its a social network with PHP API, so am not very sure wether this is all. any heads ups will be greatful

Comment: @NgesBrian just use search for `.htaccess` in pointed manual and it will solve your problem with not found pages

Comment: Yes, my website can route properly now but I think my JS is not loaded on the build even when i move it to the home and do all of the above

Comment: thanks again, it seems to be working but having a different issue. there is a particular library i use for translation call lingui. when I build my application, it executes the native components but when it reaches this component, it stops and instead display the id of this component. i dont still know what i am missing here. Do not know wether it is my issue or or it is that of the library because all my css and Nav bar seems to be ok

Comment: What the error do you have? BTW, maybe you post your current problem in the separate ticket?